# How can we test Ionic 2 applications on mobile?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have developed an application using ionic 2, angular2 on visual studio code editor using Google chrome as a browser in the Desktop.Now I want to test my application on mobile.
Is there any tool for that? Or what else can be the best possible method.

Answer (score 1):

Three types of testing:

- Real Device / Emulator (Manual)

`ionic run ios/android [--emulator]`

- Unit testing

Karma/Jasmine is available for this purpose. This is basically same as desktop.

- End-to-end testing

Use Protractor/Appium for automated test on the real app. For some guides on this, search or see [here](http://tombuyse.com/end-to-end-testing-an-ionic-application-with-appium-and-protractor).

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 types of testing.

1. Desktop browser testing
2. Simulator testing
3. Mobile browser testing
4. Testing as a native app

This [**official doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html) explains each testing clearly.Please see that.

Comment: Hi Sampath, While testing with the fourth point that you have mentioned and following the official document, I ran command `ionic run android`.The following error is displayed: `ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk

Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper`.

Although I have updated the Android Studio.

Comment: Please see this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo-ur-android-sdk/22056/26

Comment: @Sampath..This issue is solved and the build is successfully completed and apk is generated in the output folder.But then the following error message is displayed.
`BUILD SUCCESSFUL



Total time: 9.35 secs

Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Users/Lenovo/walkin1/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk


ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1`
How do I test the application in mobile ?

Comment: If you have an `apk` then try to install it on your device and see what will happen?

Comment: But I have already made an apk with ionic cloud package.and the application is not working correctly on mobile but it is working on the chrome browser of computer.so that is why i need to do testing of the ionic2 application.If you can suggest something...

Comment: What will happen when you run this? `ionic run android --device`

Comment: The following message is displayed:
`Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Users/Lenovo/walkin1/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Using apk: C:/Users/Lenovo/walkin1/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Package name: com.ionicframework.walkin1907106

LAUNCH SUCCESS`
And the application is started in my device.:):)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141934/discussion-between-aditya-jain-and-sampath).

Answer (score 0):

You can test with following approaches:

**In browser:**

> command

```
ionic serve

ionic serve --lab
```

**In Simulator**

> command

```
ionic build platform-name (eg. ionic build android)
```

than

```
ionic emulate android
```

**In Mobile:**

Install app in mobile using android studio via USB debugging.

> *In All three case Browser, Simulator and mobile.*

While running app either in browser, simulator or in mobile, you can inspect your app in chrome browser. Type in chrome address-bar

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

Answer (score 0):

For browser testing

```
ionic serve
```

For Mobile Testing

```
ionic run android
```

For making an APK and install as an app on mobile. You need to install android SDK

```
ionic build android
```