# Test ionic 2 app without android studio

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

Due to certain reasons I can't download android studio. And I recently incorporated sqlite DB in my app. As far as i know, `ionic serve` cannot run a sqlite DB. I wanted to know if it's possible to test my ionic 3.x app on an android device without having android studio.

Comment: you need to install the [command line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Comment: So this will enable me to run my app on my android device but does this also include an emulator?

Comment: no you will have to use the android virtual device manager tool and sdk manager tool to download and setup emulator

Comment: Oh ok. Going back to the command line tools, could you guide me through

Comment: You can find answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422552/how-can-we-test-ionic-2-applications-on-mobile/43426174#43426174

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Android studio at all to work on Ionic development. Any editor + a terminal will do.

Having said that it is *strongly* recommended to work with the free [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editor, as it's built by Microsoft, the same team that built Typescript which makes coding there a great experience.

I also suggest [this set of plugins](http://devboosts.com/2017/02/08/top-10-vs-code-extensions/index.html) to get you started.

Unfortunately you cannot work on SQLite in the browser but I strongly recommend you use [`ionic-storage`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage) anyway, which provides a single API and will use automatically whatever best storage method is available in the current platform, with no additional effort from you.

---

Ionic Storage is a package created and maintained by the ionic team to abstract development from the specifics of each browser or platform and automatically use the best storage solution available.

## 1. Installing Dependencies

In your case for SQLite you need to first install the dependencies for both Angular and Cordova:

`npm install @ionic/storage --save`

and

`cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage --save`

Then edit your NgModule declaration in `src/app/app.module.ts` to add `IonicStorageModule` as an import:

```js
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
      name: '__mydb',
      driverOrder: ['indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql'],
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [...],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [...],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

## 2. Inject Storage module into your component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}
}
```

## 3. Using Ionic Storage

Whenever you access storage, make sure to always wrap your code in the following:

```
storage.ready().then(() => { /* code here safely */});
```

#### 3.1 Saving a key-value pair

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
    storage.set('some key', 'some value');
});
```

#### 3.2 Retrieving a value

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
  storage.get('age').then((val: string) => {
      console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
});
```

#### 3.3 Deleting a key-value pair

```
storage.ready().then(() => {
    storage.remove('key').then((key: string) => { /* do something after deletion */})
});
```